# List of software and versions for test data

Tags: data-request, programming

Does anybody know where I can find some sample data to use as stub data for my application to test with I don't want it to be just random strings and numbers?

I was originally going to user Microsoft "Ready for Windows" list but this appears to have vanished. I'm looking for a list of Software with Vendor, Application Name and Version e.g. (Mozilla, Firefox, 85.0).

In terms of quantity as many as possible (thousands if possible) and format doesn't really matter as I can write some code to deal with that.

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the data yourself :-)

If you know a bit about JavaScript and Node programming: take a look at the free "Faker.js" third-party library.

Scroll down on the [Faker.js GitHub page](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) to see what categories of fake data can be generated (Fake Addresses, Computer Lingo, Business-Gibberish, Lorem-Ipsums, Dates...)

I think there are implementations of Faker.js available in other languages,e.g. Perl and Python. Or rather it was the other way around . JavaScript implementation came second.